# OrchardCMS - How to make an inline blog

Tags: orchardcms, blogs

I am fairly new to OrchardCMS, I am trying to make an inline blog, something similar to http://carsquare.com/Content/CarReviews

Any idea how I can achieve this using standard blog functionality, or do I need to custom write the module?

Thanks

Comment: If you mean to only style it a little different, you can just override the specific shapes in your theme

Answer (score 0):

I think the Orchard Blog looks like that more or less. You can install a theme, that will get you a step closer. And then maybe change the Page views. Just enable the shapetracing module and have a look around.